# Using cookie with HTTPS

Tags: cookies, https, jquery-cookie

I'm working on https and I had a problem about a cookie

If I deploy in a http, cookie is stored and read normally. But when deploy in https, cookie is not stored and read also even though I set a "secure=true" in a jquery cookie configuration like this

```
$.cookie("mycookie", "hello", { expires: 365, path: "/", secure: true });
```

and...

```
$.cookie("mycookie", "hello", { expires: 365, path: "/" }); is not work as well
```

Do you have some idea to get the cookie works with https protocol?